# Matching the rightmost and the leftmost symbols in perl with regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match a string such that the leftmost symbol and the rightmost symbol are the same. How do I do that?

Comment: @tchrist, any alphanumerical character. I just wanted a formal answer. I can construct the expression myself.

Comment: Symbols are `\pS`; letters are `\pL`; numbers are `\pN`; alphabetics are `\p{alpha}`, which includes various marks and symbols, and excludes certain numbers. I’ve given you a formal answer.

Comment: @tchrist, Are there any symbol that represents binary numbers?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean.  There are code points that can be used to represent binary digits, by virtue of having `\p{Numeric_Value=1}` or `\p{Numeric_Value=0}`. All of these are of type `\p{Number}` and not type `\p{Symbol}`, but they are variously distributed among the three different number general categories, and not restricted to digits alone. You might wish to use only regular digits, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string =~ m/^(.).*\1$/
```

should work.  This fails to match strings of length 1, though.

Comment: I think (.) groups the first symbol and \1 denotes the first group. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  I just added a link to my answer with some more information for you.

Comment: I’m afraid @gzg has added more stipulations, and so your pattern no longer meets what he asked for.

Comment: You'll have to play the games that tchrist shows to match an alphanumerical as clarified in the question comments. Also, since Unicode's fuzzy idea of a character is different than most humans, you don't want to end up in the middle of a grapheme probably.

Comment: Also note that the $ anchor allows one character after it. \z doesn't though.

Comment: I should say that the $ anchor allows _at least_ one character after it. If someone has set default regex flags with a `/m` (a v5.14 feature), it can have an unlimited number of characters after it.

Comment: That will match whitespace in the capture group, which seem to be something he doesn’t want. It will also fail to traverse newlines. And within the scope of a `use re "/m"` declaration, it will do stranger things still.

Answer (score 2):

It’s impossible to know exactly what you mean without clarification of what you consider a “symbol”, but here is one possible solution:

```
use Unicode::Normalize;
NFD($string) =~ / \A \s* ( (?= \p{Grapheme_Base} ) \X ) .* \1 \s* \z /sx;
```

and here is another:

```
use Unicode::Normalize;
NFD($string) =~ / \A \s* ( (?= \p{Symbol} ) \X ) .* \1 \s* \z /sx;
```

and here is one more:

```
use Unicode::Normalize;
NFD($string) =~ / \A \s* ( (?: (?= \p{Symbol} ) \X )+ ) .* \1 \s* \z /sx;
```

And it is even possible that you might be able in some very limited circumstances be able to get away with:

```
$string =~ / ^ (\pS) .* \1 $ /xs;
```

But if you do, it’s also likely that someday you’re going to wish you had been more careful.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try; looks like it's going to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this with a regex? Is it homework? I avoid regexes for trivial patterns like this.

```
 use Unicode::Normalize qw(NFC);
 $s = NFC( $s );

 substr( $s, 0, 1 ) eq substr( $s, -1, 1 );
```

Because Tom will complain about characters versus graphemes, you can handle that too:

```
 use v5.10.1;
 use Unicode::GCString;
 use Unicode::Normalize qw(NFC);

 my $gcs = Unicode::GCString->new( NFC( $s ) );
 $gcs->substr( 0, 1 ) eq $gcs->substr( -1, 1 )
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you want `$gcs->substr(0,1)` and `$gcs->substr(-1,1)`. And even then there’s a problem, because unless both sides are first normalized to the same form, that won’t always work. Well, ok, you could call `Unicode::Collate->new->eq( $gcs->substr(0,1), $gcs->substr(-1,1) )`, but that’s getting out of hand; best to just normalize first. —— But mostly I was worried about getting a proper printing character out of it, not whitespace or control characters or orphaned marks, and to be whitespace-tolerant.

Comment: Yes, always normalize. What ever happened to your proposal to make that an IO layer (or was that something we just talked about in email?)

Comment: No, you can’t use `->as_string`, because you’ll generate a false positive with something like `"\x{305} xxx b\x{305}"`. You have to use the real `->substr` method that works on graphemes, not the `substr` function that works on code points. —— I may have mentioned the I/O layer things on p5p some time ago; I don’t recall. I think I sent you code that simulated this with a double background fork for pre- and post-processing.

Comment: Huh, then the Unicode::GCString docs are wrong. The CAVEAT section shows it using a regular substr.

Comment: It’s not wrong; it’s just misleading. As soon as you do the function `substr` instead of the method `->substr`, you switch back from graphemes to code points. The CAVEAT section is warning about implicit `->as_string` conversions from a `q("")` overload triggering the conversion. But you still are carving out code points not graphemes. Run my test string.

Answer (score 0):

These regex's match strings with length 1 and greater. In the expressions, `(.)` represent a capture group where the dot should be substituted with your class of symbols I guess (see Unicode guru's, although that does not seem to be the intent of the question).

The context of this regex is single line (`/s` modifier). It allows the dot to match 
newlines as well as anything else (like `[\s\S]`) so newlines can be embedded as well as being the outter most delimeter.

Using `\z` is the same as `$` (in `/s` mode), except `\z` corrects a scenario where `$` could match  before a newline (matches at the end of string is more commona). If the character in question is a newline and you use un-greedy quantifier (like `.*?`) and the target string is "\nasdf\n\n", it could falsly match before the final newline. But that is a moot issue since the match is all greedy. Still, leave it in for grins.

```
/^(?=(.)).*\1\z/s
```

expanded

```
/
 ^           # Beginning of string
 (?=(.))     # Lookahead - capture grp1, first (any) character (but don't consume it)
 .*          # Optionally consume all the characters up until before the last character
 \1          # Backreference to capture grp1, this must exist
 \z          # End of string
/s    # s modifier
```

Example stipulating just word class characters

```
/^(?=(\w)).*\1\z/s
```

Again, just substitute your acceptable symbols

Comment: The `/s` has no effect on the `$` anchor. You're thinking about `/m`. The `/s` merely lets a . match a newline. A default `/m`, though, will let your `^` match at the beginning of a logical line, which is why Tom uses the `\A` instead. The `\w` matches more than alphanumerics, too. It's any identifier character.

Comment: @brian d foy - Was explaining the differnt effect's of /^(?=(.)).*\1$/, /^(?=(.)).*?\1$/s, /^(?=(.)).*\1$/s, /^(?=(.)).*?\1\z/s, /^(?=(.)).*\1\z/s when matching a target string of `\n`, `\n\n`, or `\n\n\n`. Its moot if `\n` is not a selectable character. I guess I could have used `/^(?=([^\W_])).*\1\z/s` as a broader stipulation, thanks for the heads up. And thanks for hilighting my post for me.